# SQL Server Management

Tags: sql-server, sql

Доброго времени суток всем!

У меня на почте появился банер этого сайта. Решил воспользоваться. Подскажите, кто может. Установил  SQL Server Management Studio Express.  Он при запуске спрашивает имя сервера, пароль и тип сервера.  Вопрос:  а он может вообще работать на локальном компе (без сети и сервера) и если да, то что ему сказать?

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас полный SQL Server то попробуйте в качестве имени сервера `(local)`, если SQL Server Express - `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`. Тип сервера - "Компонент Database Engine". Если в Windows работаете под пользователем с правами администратора, можете поставить проверку подлинности Windows (не нужно будет указывать логин и пароль). При проверке подлинности SQL Server логин администратора `sa`. Пароль - тот, который вы указывали при установке/настройке сервера.

Comment: "Пароль и тип сервера, думаю, вам известны..."Извиняюсь , возможно я не совсем точно задал вопрос. Да в том-то идело, что не известны. Работаю дома на своём единственном компе.При установке он (SQL Serv. Manag.)  спросил 
Имя  и Компанию. А вот при запуске запрашивает Имя сервера, Имя входа и Пароль.  Что ему отвечать?

Comment: Судя по всему вы установили только SQL Server Management Studio, но не установили сам сервер. Скачайте, установите.  А пока вам просто не к чему подключаться )

Comment: Nofate - спасибо.  Скачал Express Edish 2005.  Смущает, что в списке операционных систем под него нет Wind7  ( у меня Wind7).
Будет он с ней работать?

Comment: Куда он денется. Все работает под 7.

Answer (score 1):

Пароль и тип сервера, думаю, вам известны. А имя сервера попробуйте **localhost** или **127.0.0.1**. Это, конечно, при условии, что сервер у Вас крутится на машине.