# Получение значения server name

Tags: sql-server, sql

Я забыл, что написал во время установки в `SQL server name`. И сейчас не получается `connect`. Как можно узнать этот `server name`?

Comment: При установке чего? Куда забил? Какой именно SQL-сервер? Чем подключаетесь? 

`//ушел за хрустальным шаром`

Comment: хрустальный шар был рядом со мной.спасибо за ответ

Comment: TITLE: Подключение к серверу


Не удается подключиться к USER-PC


ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНАЯ ИНФОРМАЦИЯ:

Связанные с сетью или экземпляра конкретных Произошла ошибка при установлении соединения с SQL Server.Сервер не найден или не доступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра правильно и что данных SQL Server настроен для удаленных подключений. (Поставщик: поставщик именованных каналов, ошибка: 40 - Не удалось открыть подключение к SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: Ну вот хотя бы удалось выпытать, что это `Microsoft SQL Server`. Посмотрите ссылку от @null.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно [эта тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/43414/sql-server-management) поможет. А вообще если сервер локальный то можно вместо имени написать (local) или просто поставить точку - т.е. подключиться к локальному серверу ( не знаю за другие версии MS SQL, но в 2008 сервере точно работает ).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Сейчас работает